# Laravel middleware returning (Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object) error

Tags: laravel, middleware

I'm getting **error** when I wrap a resource route to my custom middleware

My **middleware**:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Middleware;

 use Closure;
 use Auth;

class Officer
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'title_officer') {
            return $next($request);
        }
        // elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'agent') {
        //     return redirect('/agent');
        // }
        // else {
        //     return redirect('/customer');
        // }
    }
}
```

The resource **route** using the middleware:

```
Route::resource('new-order', 'BackendController')->middleware('officer');
```

I'm getting error:

> (Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object).

**How to fix it ?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In middleware, it is important to handle all cases and return the redirects accordingly or abort.

You do `return $next($request);` when you want to allow system to continue processing the request ahead.

However, if in case `if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'title_officer')` condition fails, you have not mentioned what system should do.

You can may be `abort(404)` if  you do not want to show the page as available or  maybe `abort(403)` for access forbidden.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'title_officer') {
            return $next($request);
        }
        abort(403);
    }
```

But make sure you do not add a case which will make an infinite loop. Please check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware) for more options.

Answer (score 3):

just use some thing like this in middleware : RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
     if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
         // your condition
         return redirect('the route name');
     }
}
```

Comment: Great! I was missing the redirect helper.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error. In my controller I had

`return route('dashboard')` 
instead of 
 `return redirect()->route('dashboard')`

That should fix it

Answer (score 0):

try adding an `else` block which returns when your `if` condition isn't met:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'title_officer') {
            return $next($request);
        }else{
           return back();
        }
    }
```

Comment: the missing else block was creating the problem, but now i fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check middleware function and you have missed below one_

```
return $next($request);
```

so add this line.

Answer (score -1):

Late but.. This happens to me when column in DB was null.