# Login check not working Laravel-Middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing middleware to check login and register in Kernel but get the error below

> Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if(Auth::check()){
                return $next($request);
            }
            return route('login');
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel middleware returning (Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643562/laravel-middleware-returning-trying-to-get-property-headers-of-non-object-er)

Comment: middleware have to return responses, not strings, it is a stack the request has to pass through and the response has to pass back out of the stack

Answer (score -1):

Why would you do this manually? Just install the laravel/ui package

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

And run this command

```
php artisan ui:auth
```

Then on the routes include this middleware 'auth:api'

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing `redirect()` function

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check()){
        return $next($request);
    }
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```