# Laravel 7.30 Redirect to dashbaord panel when user enter /login page

Tags: php, laravel

I have currently when `user` or `superadministrator` login into website, automatically redirect to `management/panel/dashboard` or `user/panel/dashboard`. but when a user or superadministrator write the address manually `sitename.com/login`, i need redirect to `management/panel/dashboard` or `user/panel/dashboard` with check user has role `Superadministrator` or `User` and redirected to it. I hope I've correctly stated what I mean.

also i use `$user->hasRole` but i get this error :

```
Call to a member function hasRole() on null
```

> I use santigarcor/laratrust": "5.2.* package for role and permission.

RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {

        $user = Auth::user();
        // if (auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')) {
        //     dd('ok');
        // } else {
        //     dd('no');
        // }
        
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        //if( $user->hasRole('superadministrator') )
            //return redirect('management/panel/dashboard');
                //return redirect('user/panel/dashboard');

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Comment: when you call `Auth::user()` there is no user so it is null. And you are calling `null->hasRole()`. You should do `if (auth()->user() && auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'))` or `$user && $user->hasRole()`

Comment: i test `auth()->user()` but still this error `Call to a member function hasRole() on null`

Comment: Try that `$user = Auth::user();
        
        if(!$user){
            return $next($request);
        }

        if($user && $user->hasRole('admin')){
            return redirect('');
        }

        if($user && $user->hasRole('admin')){
            return redirect('');
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for `hasRole` within `Auth::guard($guard)->check()` if statement. Do something like this:

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

    if (Auth::user()->hasRole('user'))
    {
        return redirect('/user-dashboard');
    }elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('superadmin'))
    {
        return redirect('/superadmin-dashboard');
    }
}

return $next($request);
```

for more: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i changed function but receive `Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object` error.

Comment: its because u r not handling redirects properly. see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54643562/laravel-middleware-returning-trying-to-get-property-headers-of-non-object-er

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Auth::user()->hasRole('superadministrator')){
     return redirect('management/panel/dashboard');
}else{
     return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if user don’t  have `superadministrator ` permission, redirect to `user/panel/dashboard` ?

Comment: when i click on `logout` btn, show this error `Call to a member function hasRole() on null
`